# Android Application that connects to remote server

Tags: java, android, android-2.2-froyo

I am trying to build an Android App on Platform 2.2 Froyo. The app is supposed to connect to a remote server, fetch data from it and display to user in a different language.

- **So my question - What technologies I need to learn so that I can
  build the above app.**

Note - I have already installed the Android platform and have built simple apps like Hello, world. I know Java. Also I am using Eclipse.

Thank you for your answers. No rude comment please...

//--------------Code for connecting to web using HTTP protocol-----------------//

```
package in.androidbook.Networking;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    ImageView img;
    /* This is for making asynchronous calls to ensure that connection to server will not return until data is received */

    private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
    {
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String...url)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage(url[0]);
            return bitmap;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);         
        }
    }
    // Code for making HTTP connection
    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException 
    {
        InputStream in = null;
        int response = -1;

        URL url = new URL(urlString);//We take an object of class URL
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); //Create a connection object and open the connection

        if(!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection)) throw new IOException("Not an Http connection");
        try
        {
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn; //httpConn object is assigned the value of conn. Typecasting is done to avoid conflict.
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();

            if(response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        }
        return in;
    }   
        //------------------------------------------ OpenHttpConnection method completed----------------------------------------------------------//
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    //-------------------------------Method to download an image--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try
        {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, e1.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Toast displays a short msg to user. this refers to current object.
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }  


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

       Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage("http://i.zdnet.com/blogs/3-29-androids.jpg");
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED (based on comment) : As we are talking about the client side, I confirm my answer. If the site is not yours, the first thing you need to do if check how/if it allows for some kind of communication via API, and in what kind of format (XML and JSON being the most used). With this information, it should be pretty easy. Take a look of the Android example using the Google Map or Twitter, you should find some.

Well, it depends what do you mean exactly : are you asking for the skills needed on the client side (the app) - in the idea that the server is already built, or will be by someone else, or the skills needed for the server ?

In the former case, I would advice to communicate with REST API and JSON. Take a look at apache HTTPGet, HTTPClient and HTTPResponse class and org.json (all are included in Android). If you want to test with them, use some public APIs (so you do not have to worry about the server), such as Google Map API (which is simple and free to use under some limits).

In the latter case, I'm with ColWinters : if you know java, use it there also, with Tomcat as a server and a basic Servlet. You'll find examples aplenty on the Internet.

Comment: Thank you. To be more specific.... I want to know where/how should I begin to develop an "ANDROID APP that connects to a website and downloads and displays data." The website is a normal website like a weather website, music website or Google maps website as you mentioned. Again thank you.

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Martin, thank you for you answer. Well, I am trying to connect to this website: http://www.kvkkolhapur.com/ which obviously is not owned by me. It's a government website. So do I need to contact the web administrator to get the details. As you said, I will first work with Google Map example. Thank you again. Your answer was helpful.

Comment: (reply to Jan 30). Martin I am sorry I am returning back after 2 months. In you comment you mention that very first, I should check how the website communicates (through JSON or some API). I checked the website - it shows only HTML code. How can I figure it out? Let's say that I wish you give weather services on my map. Here is the link on the website - http://www.kvk.pravara.com/weather.html 

Uptil now - I have learnt how to build a "GridView" user interface. I also learnt how to use HTTP protocol to connect to the web and downloaded an image. I am posting code in my answer. Thank you

Comment: Problem here is that as (I suppose) you are not the owner of the website, you are dependent of what they offer. It seems to be a "HTML only" website, so collecting info would be difficult (you have to parse the HTML) and brittle (your code will break if they change some formatting). In addition, be sure to check that this is legal (websites are Intellectual Property in most countries).

Comment: thank you for the information. In between I just got lost between semantics of various types of data formats and technologies to parse them. 

Thank you for all the information and reminiding about intellectual proerty rights. 

As for my application I have taken a very different approach. I am avoiding downloading and parsing of HTML data as per suggestion.

Thank you again for your time and advice.

Answer (score 1):

Look up these technologies,

Apache Tomcat - Java Server Pages (server processing)
MySQL (storage of data)

and thats it. Also make sure to do the request in a seperate thread like an Async Task from an activity.

Comment: ColWinters, thank you for your answers. The server is website on the internet, that I intend to connect to and download the data. I am not gettinh how the role of Apache Tomcat comes into play here. Well, what I am supposing that that learning the technologies you mentioned would give me an idea what I need to build in my app. Am I right? Again thank you.

Comment: Tomcat is an add-on to the Apache open source Web Server. Read up on these topics and you'll figure it out. I assumed you meant a web based server.

Answer (score 1):

If you know java, I would suggest servlet as service hosted on server which reads data from mysql or anydatabase and contructs as json. in your android app make http using in buit httpclient to remote servlet and parse json response. So. Servlets,Httpclient,Json covers most if your app is native to phone app.